# How do I place an image overlapping two rows in a grid

Tags: html, css

So I have an image of a panda that is meant to 'hang' on the black line on my web page, but the issue is, it's not lowering over the `.top` portion of the `.background`, which it needs to, to overlap over the two parts `.top` and `.bottom` in the grid.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #179CA5;
}

.background {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 5fr;
  grid-template-areas: "backgroundTop" "backgroundBottom";
}

.background .top {
  grid-area: backgroundTop;
  background-color: #179CA5;
}

.background .top img {
  display: block;
  margin: 10vh auto 0 auto;
  padding-right: 3vw;
  max-height: 13rem;
  max-width: 13rem;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  border: 3px orange solid;
}

.background .bottom {
  grid-area: backgroundBottom;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="top">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ki4auk5.png" alt="Panda">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Web page: https://gyazo.com/e3bee60f6a873837c0f3241cd4a8e180

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oumkL0p3/) to help, you can see what I mean there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `top: 50px` in your `img` block, change `50px` to fit your need.

https://jsfiddle.net/7y91mdh4/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just add a negative bottom margin to the image. Just like that:

```
.background .top img {
  margin-bottom: -45px;
}
```